# how to use single input textbox to write multiple inputs to the hardware using winform and socket programming c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, hardware-interface

I am working on a C# Algorithm in which i need to write dynamic inputs to the hardware platform. I am new to c# But i do have an algorithm in which i can write single input using winform textbox.
Now i am trying to use the same winform, apply any iterative loop and update the values on the winform textboxes to get dynamic inputs, so i can have multiple outputs continuously.
This is the following design equation on which my hardware model is working

```
Fx= kxx( x-xt) 
Fy = kyy(y-yt)
```

Text boxes are

```
Kxx, kyy, xt, yt
```

I wanna apply some algorithm on kx and ky so i can have multple values for Fx and Fy. 
But again my winform right now is working on just one input i.e if i write discrete values to the textboxes and hit the button target_pos then hardware handle is moving toward given target. The syntax for the particular part is the following:

```
private void set_target_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //parse params into 1 string
                byte[] ui8Buffer = new byte[77];
                byte[] floatByte = new byte[4];

                float kxx = float.Parse(k_xx_textbox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                float kyy = float.Parse(k_yy_textbox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                float kxy = float.Parse(k_xy_textbox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                float kyx = float.Parse(k_yx_textbox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                float bxx = float.Parse(b_xx_textbox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                float byy = float.Parse(b_yy_textbox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                float bxy = float.Parse(b_xy_textbox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                float byx = float.Parse(b_yx_textbox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                float tar_gain = float.Parse(target_gain_textbox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                float tar_rot_angle = float.Parse(target_rot_textbox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                float targetx = float.Parse(targ_X_textbox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
                float targety = float.Parse(targ_Y_textbox.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);

                //pack into 1 data
                ui8Buffer[0] = packetCheck[0];
                ui8Buffer[1] = packetCheck[1];
                ui8Buffer[2] = CMD_MSG;
                ui8Buffer[3] = 0x00;
                ui8Buffer[4] = 0x08;
                ui8Buffer[5] = 67;
                //ui8Buffer[6] = (byte)(N_target_index_comboBox.SelectedIndex + 1);
                ui8Buffer[6] = (byte)(EXERCIZE_TARG);

                ui8Buffer[7] = (byte)(((Int16)targetx) >> 8);
                ui8Buffer[8] = (byte)(((Int16)targetx));
                ui8Buffer[9] = (byte)(((Int16)targety) >> 8);
                ui8Buffer[10] = (byte)(((Int16)targety));
                ui8Buffer[11] = (byte)(en_target_comboBox.SelectedIndex);
                ui8Buffer[12] = (byte)(en_main_comboBox.SelectedIndex);
                GetBytesSingle(kxx, out floatByte);
                floatByte.CopyTo(ui8Buffer, 13);
                GetBytesSingle(kyy, out floatByte);
                floatByte.CopyTo(ui8Buffer, 17);
                GetBytesSingle(kxy, out floatByte);
                floatByte.CopyTo(ui8Buffer, 21);
                GetBytesSingle(kyx, out floatByte);
                floatByte.CopyTo(ui8Buffer, 25);
                GetBytesSingle(bxx, out floatByte);
                floatByte.CopyTo(ui8Buffer, 29);
                GetBytesSingle(byy, out floatByte);
                floatByte.CopyTo(ui8Buffer, 33);
                GetBytesSingle(bxy, out floatByte);
                floatByte.CopyTo(ui8Buffer, 37);
                GetBytesSingle(byx, out floatByte);
                floatByte.CopyTo(ui8Buffer, 41);

                GetBytesSingle(tar_gain, out floatByte);
                floatByte.CopyTo(ui8Buffer, 45);
                GetBytesSingle(tar_rot_angle, out floatByte);
                floatByte.CopyTo(ui8Buffer, 49);

                //get checksum
                ui8Buffer[73] = 0;
                for (int i = 2; i < (6 + ui8Buffer[5]); i++)
                {
                    ui8Buffer[73] ^= ui8Buffer[i];
                }
                ui8Buffer[74] = packetCheck[2];
                ui8Buffer[75] = packetCheck[3];
                ui8Buffer[76] = ENCRYPT_EN;

                Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToHexViaLookup32(ui8Buffer));

                //send data if open
                if (host_listening)
                {
                    //send data
                    // Sends data asynchronously to a connected Socket 
                    client_handler.BeginSend(ui8Buffer, 0, ui8Buffer.Length, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client_handler);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc) { MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString()); }
        }
```

Comment: You are not writing to any hardware.  You are sending messages over a communication path.  So you need to create an application protocol to send data.  A simple method would be to send either CSV data or even better is to send an XML string.

Comment: I can't see what the question is here. What problem are you having with making the code do what you want?

Comment: Hi jdweng, yeah actually this the specific part of the cade and i writing this to the hardware as well, but my question was how to change this kxx or kyy variable to multiple time so i can update the value of kxx and use this value for multiple targets.

Comment: Hi Tom, My question is related to this kxx variable if i need to make this kxx variable iterative how can i do that ?

Comment: why not use this code in an event handler like text changed, which will fire every time text on your textbox changes

Comment: Anil can you explain a bit how exactly you are suggesting ?